# BroadcastReceiver is receiving like 1 of 10 intents

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

On button click I am opening activity(ActionListActivity) and sending intent to IntentService (later this service sends broadCast intent to ActionListActivity). But I am usually receiving only the first intent after launch. Is it real that intent is sent before the receiver is registred?

**I want to get data providet by the intentService, and update my UI using it.**

Scheme Activity->IntentService->BroadCastReceiver inside ActionListActivity

Activity:

```
private void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem)
    {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.actions:{
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, ActionListActivity.class);
                this.startActivity(myIntent);
                ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                progressDialog.show();
                Intent dataIntent = new Intent(this, DatabaseWorkIntentService.class);
                dataIntent.putExtra(Utils.INTENT_SERVICE_INVOKE, Utils.READ_ACTIONS_DATA);
                startService(dataIntent);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
```

IntentService:

```
     private void readActionData(){
            Log.e("read actions data","data");
            List<Action> actionList;
            actionList = Action.listAll(Action.class);

            Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
            broadcastIntent.setAction(Utils.READ_ACTIONS_DATA);
            broadcastIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Utils.READ_ACTIONS_DATA, (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) actionList);
            sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        }
```

ActionListActivity:

```
public class ActionListActivity extends BaseActivity {

    boolean mIsReceiverRegistered = false;
    DataBroadcastReceiver receiver;
    TextView someTv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.action_list_activity);
        this.initToolbarAndDrawerWithReadableName(getString(R.string.our_actions));

        someTv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.someTv);
    }

    public void someTvTest(Action action){
        someTv.append(action.getName());
        Log.e("data",action.getName());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mIsReceiverRegistered) {
            unregisterReceiver(receiver);
            receiver = null;
            mIsReceiverRegistered = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (!mIsReceiverRegistered) {
            if (receiver == null)
                receiver = new DataBroadcastReceiver();
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
            filter.addAction(Utils.READ_ACTIONS_DATA);
            receiver.setMainActivityHandler(this);
            registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
            mIsReceiverRegistered = true;
        }
    }
}
class DataBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    ActionListActivity activity = null;
    ArrayList<Action> list;

    public void setMainActivityHandler(ActionListActivity main){
        activity = main;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("reciever","reciev");
        list = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Utils.READ_ACTIONS_DATA);
        for (Action action:list){
            if(activity!=null) {
                activity.someTvTest(action);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when asking question alongwith code also describe what you want to achieve, so that others can have a idea why you have opted for the way you are currently working.

Comment: @VivekMishra Ok, changed the question a little bit, any ideas?

Comment: what is the use of intent service?

Comment: @VivekMishra Reading some data from database, and sending it to activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start activity and service async.
You need to start service inside ActionListActivity and wait for response.

Comment: Maybe i dont understand you. You mean to send intent to IntentService inside ActionListActivity&

Comment: @Turbozanik yes, this is the only way to be sure that callback exists without  any type of storage